# jquery fading effect

Tags: jquery

i have this javascript code to which i want to add the jquery fade-in effect

```
hover.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {Core.addClass(cpanel,"on");},false);
```

Core is another library i am using. 
the above event listener just enables the cpanel div to visible state. how do i make it fade into the view. i am using jquery-ui and am very new at it.

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: No jquery-ui necessary on this one, karim79 sums it up nicely

Comment: What do the Core and cpanel variables in your code represent? Is there another JavaScript library in use in your code?

Comment: yes i already mentioned that. pls see post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your cpanel div has a class of 'on', you could do this:

```
$('.on').fadeIn("slow"); //.fadeIn("normal"); or .fadeIn("fast");
```

See jQuery's [fadeIn effect](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn)

Comment: i have a doubt. in the above snippet you havent mentioned cpanel which is the div i want to display?

Comment: @amit - give your cpanel div an ID like id="cpanel" and set the style to style="display:none" and then do $('#cpanel').fadeIn("slow");

Comment: thanks a lot @karim. it works. now how do i remove the div from displaying on mouseout? i was using this: hover.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {Core.removeClass(cpanel,"on");},false);

Comment: i tried using .fadeOut. it fades the cpanel. but it reappears/fades/reappers....i mean to say it continues to fade-out-fade-in forever.

Comment: @amit - sounds like it's conflicting with that other script. Try disabling that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeIn:

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn#speedcallback

If you still want to use your snippet to add that class (which can also be done in jQuery btw), just put the jQuery fadein code before it.  This will cause the fadeIn effect to happen, and then just add the (probably redundant) "on" class.

In response to comment:
This is the code I would try first

```
hover.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {
  cpanel.fadeIn("slow"); // this is if cpanel is a jQuery object.  If it is an element, do $(cpanel).fadeIn("slow");
  Core.addClass(cpanel,"on");
}, false);
```

If that still doesn't work, can you let me know what is happening, if anything?  Thanks.